# How to ensure shinyjs::runjs runs after DOM updates?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinyjs

I have an app where I update a `uiOutput` with new content, and then need to run a javascript function on the client side to manipulate it. I'm using `shinyjs::runjs()` to run the javascript, using `observeEvent()` when the HTML content, contained in a `reactive()`, changes.

The timing of the events, however, is that the javascript runs before the page is updated. I would like to have the javascript run after the DOM is updated with the new content from the server.

Here's a reproducible example (the use of `setTimeout` is only for demonstration of the delay):

````
---
title: Test
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r, echo=FALSE}
shiny::addResourcePath("shinyjs", system.file("srcjs", package = "shinyjs"))
```

```{r, context='server'}
shinyjs::useShinyjs(html = TRUE)
```
<script src="shinyjs/inject.js"></script>


Column {.sidebar}
------------------------------------

```{r}
shiny::numericInput('js_time', label = 'JS timeout (ms)', min = 0, step = 100, value = 0)
actionButton('button', 'Update')
```


Column
------------------------------------

```{r context='render'}
uiOutput("contentBox")
```

```{r context='server'}
content <- reactive({
  input$button
  x = rnorm(1)
  shiny::tags$div(x, id = 'mydiv')
})

output$contentBox <- renderUI({
  content()
})

observeEvent(content(), {
  js_time = isolate(input$js_time)
  js = glue::glue('setTimeout(function(){{ console.log($("#mydiv").text()); }}, {js_time});')
  shinyjs::runjs(js)  
})

```
````

When you check the console, you can see that if you don't set a delay in the javascript (0ms in the setTimeout), the console.log report of the random number is lagged:

[image: console output does not match DOM; is lagged]

However, if you set a timeout of 100ms, the javascript code runs after the DOM is updated and the output is no longer lagged:

[image]

My question is: using shiny, is there a natural way of *ensuring* that javascript will run after the DOM is updated?

*(not sure it is relevant, but I will also mention that in my actual application, the DOM may not contain the same elements -- and the javascript may not be run -- on every update)*

Comment: Did you try a `$(document).ready`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Would that work on every click of the update button? My understanding is that that would only fire when the DOM is initially ready, not when parts of it get updated from the server.

Comment: @ richarddmorey, sorry, my idea was stupid. May be you could find a clue [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3348).